# Issues with getting output from JOIN query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, count

I am attempting a join which I am not positive if it is structured correctly, but it is not failing. The query I am working on it `$query2`. I am trying to `SELECT` match where the id of the form_categories table is equal to the category_id in the forum_topics table and count the amount there are. Basically if there are 10 different topics in a certain category, I want 10 to display.

My code is dying right where I am trying to output the info. It just disappears from my page.

IF my query is correct in what I am trying to do, this is the output that is failing...

```
<?php $numrows2 = mysqli_num_rows($query2);?>
<?php if ($numrows2 >= 0) : ?>
    <?php while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)) : ?>
        <?php $threads = $row['tid2']; ?>
        <div class="discussions_right">
        <p>Threads<?php echo $threads; ?></p>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Full Code

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM forum_categories ORDER BY category_section ASC, category_title ASC")
or die ("Query failed: %s\n".($query->error));
$query2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT t.*, COUNT(c.id) AS tid FROM forum_topics AS t JOIN forum_categories AS c")
or die ("Query2 failed: %s\n".($query2->error));
?>
<?php if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0): ?>
<div class="discussions_table">
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)): ?>
        <?php if($row['category_section'] !== $category_section): ?>
            <?php $category_section = $row['category_section'] ?>

            <div class="category_section">
                <?= $category_section ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>         
        <div class="category_border">
            <div class="discussions_left">
                <div class="discussions_category_title">
                    <a href="forum_view_category.php?cid=<?= $row['id'] ?>">
                        <?= $row['category_title'] ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="discussions_category_description">
                    <?= $row['category_description'] ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php $numrows2 = mysqli_num_rows($query2);?>
            <?php if($numrows2 >= 0):?>
                <?php while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)): ?>
                    <?php $threads = $row['tid2']; ?>

            <div class="discussions_right">
                <p>Threads<?php echo $threads; ?></p>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?> 
                <p>Posts</p>
            </div>
        </div>      
    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else: ?>
    <p>There are no posted categories available yet.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE : Showing table structures.

```
CREATE TABLE `forum_categories` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `category_section` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `category_title` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `category_description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `last_post_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `last_user_posted` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci


forum_topics
CREATE TABLE `forum_topics` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `topic_title` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `topic_creator` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `topic_last_user` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `topic_date` datetime NOT NULL,
 `topic_reply_date` datetime NOT NULL,
 `topic_views` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: You are missing the `ON` section of your `JOIN` query

Comment: When did writing legible code become so unfashionable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tested this query?

```
SELECT t.*, COUNT(c.id) AS tid FROM forum_topics AS t JOIN forum_categories AS c
```

I think it doesn't do what you're expecting. I might be wrong.

EDIT:

Try this query

```
SELECT t.*, COUNT(c.id) AS tid FROM forum_topics AS t INNER JOIN forum_categories AS c ON t.category_id = c.id
```

Comment: When I enter in my phpmyadmin I get 80? I should be getting 16. I'm not sure where that number is coming from. Again, I am not sure if I am doing the query right. I just started trying to do joins.

Comment: You need to add a condition like: ON forum.topics.primary_key = forum.categories.foreign_key.

Comment: Would I have to sub in something for primary_key/foreign_key? I've never seen that used before. I just tried to process it in my SQL and it threw errors.

Comment: Yes. Looks like maybe `cid`.

Comment: Here is what you should do in order to debug your code. Don't test the whole code. Try to debug it step by step. Because when you test the whole code, there might be more than one error which will confuse you even more. Try to comment everything up to first query. Or you can put exit; right after first query. Then var_dump($query1); This will show you what's inside the $query1. If it returns array full of data, then it works fine, and you can proceed to the next $query2. Vardump it. If it contains data then it also works fine. AND then you can go and test the first output for $query1.

Comment: Can you copy and paste a table structure (fields) for forum.categories and forum.topics? This way we can see how your tables are related and may be correct your query.

Comment: Ok. I updated my answer. Try to test the first query. use this code:   $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT category_section, category_title, category_description FROM forum_categories ORDER BY category_section ASC, category_title ASC")
or die ("Query failed: %s\n".($query->error));

exit(var_dump($query));

Comment: I get this for the first query as you requested.... `object(mysqli_result)#6 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(3) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(5) ["type"]=> int(0) }` I entered your new answer in my SQL and it outputted 16, which is correct, but when I put into my code, the output still isn't displaying in the section I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Yes. As I said, there might be more then one error. And fixing one error do not always fix the other. Ok. Now try to output only this mysqli_num_rows($query) instead of $query. Is it 0?

Comment: I did this....  `<?php if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0): 
 exit(var_dump(mysqli_num_rows($query)));?>`   .... and got `int(5)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87078/discussion-between-user1551066-and-ralph).